# How to cancel pending actions in Client Context? (Managed Client Object Model)

Tags: client-object-model

I have written a code relying on Managed Client Object Model which performs the following actions:

1. Creates a site `Web site`
2. Creates a list `List list1`
3. Creates a list field `FieldText field1` (which is a field of `list1` list)
4. Creates a list field `FieldNumber field2` (which is a field of `list1` list)
5. Creates another list `List list2`
6. Calls `clientContext.ExecuteQuery()` which orders the SharePoint to actually create all these SharePoint components.

I want to achieve the following:
If for some reason something goes wrong while creating `field2`, i.e. in the step 4, I want my code to cancel the creation of `list1`, `field1` and `field2`, but I still want the `site` and `list2` to have created.

I see the `clientContext` as a kind of a container where I can stack my commands and then call the `ExecuteQuery` method which processes these commands, i.e. pushes them to SharePoint. If I am correct, then my problem is that I am unable to clear certain commands stacked inside the `clientContext` object. I need to have them removed before the query gets executed. Can you show me how? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done using batch exception handling. Take a look at:

[How to: Use Exception Handling Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee534976.aspx)